# Getting the Node Path from Xml

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I would like to know how to get the nodepath of an Xml file. I have pasted below. So I want to create a method which will take in a node path and return me the xml for the element the nodepath points to.

The problem is suppose I want xml for FormA1 which is under the element Member (which has Mouser0 under Member/MemberName/BusinessNameLine1Txt), how can i get it since the xml also has another Member element (although with a different BusinessNameLine1Txt = Mouser1).

```
<ReturnState> 
 <ReturnDataState>      
    <Form6>
      <Header>
        <BusinessActivityCode>423690</BusinessActivityCode>
        <StateOfIncorporation>
          <State>DE</State>
          <YearOfIncorporation>2006</YearOfIncorporation>
        </StateOfIncorporation>
      </Header>
      <Body>
        <EstTaxPmtLessRefund>492823</EstTaxPmtLessRefund>
        <Overpayment>118450</Overpayment>
        <OverpaymentCreditedNxtYr>118450</OverpaymentCreditedNxtYr>
        <Reconciliation></Reconciliation>
        <SignatureArea></SignatureArea>
        <Member>                    
          <MemberName>
            <BusinessNameLine1Txt>Mouser0</BusinessNameLine1Txt>
          </MemberName>     
          <FormA1>
            <PartI-SalesFactor>
              <SalesDelOrShippedOutState>31754631</SalesDelOrShippedOutState>            
              <TotalSales>
                <Wisconsin>31754631</Wisconsin>
                <TotalCompany>1965873635</TotalCompany>
              </TotalSales>
              <SalesFactorTotal>
                <Wisconsin>31754631</Wisconsin>
                <TotalCompany>1965873635</TotalCompany>
              </SalesFactorTotal>
              <ApportionmentPercentage>0.000000</ApportionmentPercentage>
            </PartI-SalesFactor>
          </FormA1>
        </Member>
        <Member>                    
          <MemberName>
            <BusinessNameLine1Txt>Mouser1</BusinessNameLine1Txt>
          </MemberName>     
          <FormA1>
            <PartI-SalesFactor>
              <SalesDelOrShippedOutState>31754632</SalesDelOrShippedOutState>            
              <TotalSales>
                <Wisconsin>31754632</Wisconsin>
                <TotalCompany>1965873633</TotalCompany>
              </TotalSales>
              <SalesFactorTotal>
                <Wisconsin>31754632</Wisconsin>
                <TotalCompany>196587344</TotalCompany>
              </SalesFactorTotal>
              <ApportionmentPercentage>1.000000</ApportionmentPercentage>
            </PartI-SalesFactor>
          </FormA1>
        </Member>
      </Body>
    </Form6>
  </ReturnDataState>
</ReturnState>
```

So if I were to pass the method a path,

ReturnState/ReturnDataState/Form6/Body/Member/FormA1 and would like it to return

```
  <FormA1>
    <PartI-SalesFactor>
        <SalesDelOrShippedOutState>31754631</SalesDelOrShippedOutState>
        <TotalSales>
            <Wisconsin>31754631</Wisconsin>
            <TotalCompany>1965873635</TotalCompany>
        </TotalSales>
        <SalesFactorTotal>
            <Wisconsin>31754631</Wisconsin>
            <TotalCompany>1965873635</TotalCompany>
        </SalesFactorTotal>
        <ApportionmentPercentage>0.000000</ApportionmentPercentage>
    </PartI-SalesFactor>
</FormA1>
```

And not the other FormA1 under the different Member element. How would I do that ?

Thanks a lot in Advance !!

AJ.

Comment: How do you differentiate the FormA1 element that you want from the one you don't? Do you always want to get the first matching element? Or is there some other criteria?

Comment: Sounds like [xpath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256115%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Hi StriplingWarrior, Thank you for the quick reply. That would be the one of the challenges I am facing, suppose I want to retrieve the FormA1 from the second member element. How would I be able to accomplish that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an XPath query like this:

```
var xElement = XElement.Parse(str); //or however you load your xml document
var formA1 = xElement.XPathSelectElement("ReturnDataState/Form6/Body/Member/FormA1");
Console.WriteLine(formA1.ToString());
```

Because I used `XPathSelectElement` instead of `XPathSelectElements`, you'll only get the first matching element. If you want to choose your results based on other criteria, there are other tricks you can use with xpath, like the `position()` selector.

Comment: Hi StriplingWarrior, Thank you for the quick reply. That would be the one of the challenges I am facing, suppose I want to retrieve the FormA1 from the second member element. How would I be able to accomplish that ?

Comment: @user3375390: If you want the second one, you can use an xpath with `/FormA1[position()=2]` instead of just `/FormA1`. But the reason I asked the question in my comment on your original question is that I suspect you  need to get a specific one based on some criteria, but you didn't provide enough information for us to know how *you* know which element you want to select.

Answer (score 1):

[.net](/questions/tagged/.net) has several ways to run XPath against XML document, one is mentioned in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33112049/2998271) by StriplingWarrior, so I believe xpath is the way to go here. You can use XPath predicate (`[...]`) to return only elements that fulfill certain criteria. For example, you can use the following XPath expression to get only `Member` elements having grand-child `BusinessNameLine1Txt` with value equals `"Mouser0"` :

```
Member[MemberName/BusinessNameLine1Txt='Mouser0']
```

Having said that, the complete XPath expression to get `FormA1` elements of such `Member` parent would be as follow :

```
//Member[MemberName/BusinessNameLine1Txt='Mouser0']/FormA1
```

**<kbd>[`xpathtester.com demo`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/cf029d5d6159c727b26eada8bd817409)</kbd>**